# MFC Dialog not showing the resource option strings in drop-list combo

Tags: combobox, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I know you are going to ask for a example you can try but I am finding it hard to do. Sorry ....

I have a MFC dialog and I recently added a combo control:

```
COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_PUBLISHERS_TO_DISPLAY,44,18,107,46,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

Originally I added 3 text options in the data field:

1;2;3

I made sure the drop-down list area was tall enough to view all strings. Yet, when I compile it, no content was visible. In the end I deleted the strings from the data section and just added them manually.

Can you think of a setting that would cause this issue?

`DLGINIT` section:

```
IDD_DIALOG_PUBLISHERS_DATABASE DLGINIT
BEGIN
    IDC_COMBO_PUBLISHERS_TO_DISPLAY, 0x403, 2, 0
0x0031, 
    IDC_COMBO_PUBLISHERS_TO_DISPLAY, 0x403, 2, 0
0x0032, 
    IDC_COMBO_PUBLISHERS_TO_DISPLAY, 0x403, 2, 0
0x0033, 
    IDC_COMBO_GENDER, 0x403, 8, 0
0x7242, 0x746f, 0x6568, 0x0072, 
    IDC_COMBO_GENDER, 0x403, 7, 0
0x6953, 0x7473, 0x7265, "\000" 
    IDC_COMBO_SERVING_AS, 0x403, 10, 0
0x7550, 0x6c62, 0x7369, 0x6568, 0x0072, 
    IDC_COMBO_SERVING_AS, 0x403, 16, 0
0x6552, 0x7567, 0x616c, 0x2072, 0x6970, 0x6e6f, 0x6565, 0x0072, 
    IDC_COMBO_APPOINTED_AS, 0x403, 14, 0
0x6f4e, 0x2074, 0x7061, 0x6f70, 0x6e69, 0x6574, 0x0064, 
    IDC_COMBO_APPOINTED_AS, 0x403, 20, 0
0x694d, 0x696e, 0x7473, 0x7265, 0x6169, 0x206c, 0x6573, 0x7672, 0x6e61, 
0x0074, 
    IDC_COMBO_APPOINTED_AS, 0x403, 6, 0
0x6c45, 0x6564, 0x0072, 
    0
END
```

Comment: Visual Studio keeps the initialization data in a different place in *.rc file, it might be marked as `"//Dialog Info"` The resource editor might get confused if you change the control's ID. I think the initialization data cannot be Unicode, so it's not that useful.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes I had found that out about Unicode over the years. So I ended up rebuilding combos anyway from the translated STRINGTABLE data. But it was always handy for the translator to see these strings in context in the dialog, even though not translatable (in appTranslator). I suppose it is possible I renamed the combo and caused the confusion. I could see the entries in the init area though. Think I will just have to leave it.